# r studio debug location is approximate because source is not available

Tags: debugging, rstudio

I get this error

**r studio debug location is approximate because source is not available**

although I'm on the newest version of R studio with no backward slashes available in my function

My function:

```
calculate_depreciation_percentage_v1 = function (end_of_life_value_perc_temp, immediate_loss_of_value_percent, theoretische_afschrijfperiode, restwaarde_bouw_perc,bouwwaarde_perc,perceelwaarde_perc,current_nr_of_years,groeivoet_waarde_perceel, cash_flow_year_1, maintanance_cost_weights) {
  

  
  # browser()
  
  # in-function parameters: moved all of them to main script
  
  # declare variables
  end_of_life_value_perc_local = repmat(-1234, size(immediate_loss_of_value_percent,1), size(immediate_loss_of_value_percent,2))
  
  #CALCULATIONS
  

  for (RV_loop_local in 1:size(immediate_loss_of_value_percent,1)) { #for the first calculation, calculate...
    
    jaarlijks_afschrijfpercentage_bouwwaarde = (1-immediate_loss_of_value_percent[RV_loop_local,1] - restwaarde_bouw_perc) / theoretische_afschrijfperiode #ok
    depecriation_vec_bouwwaarde = seq(from = 0, to=(jaarlijks_afschrijfpercentage_bouwwaarde*size(immediate_loss_of_value_percent,2))-jaarlijks_afschrijfpercentage_bouwwaarde , by=jaarlijks_afschrijfpercentage_bouwwaarde ) + immediate_loss_of_value_percent[RV_loop_local,1]
    # depecriation_vec_bouwwaarde[1] = immediate_loss_of_value_percent[RV_loop,1] mss toepassen op hele vector, kan wel
    remaining_value_vec_bouwwaarde = (-cash_flow_year_1)*(1-depecriation_vec_bouwwaarde) # it assumed you cannot go under 0, but the program does not detect if you do...
      # tis niet juist
    #
    # (-cash_flow_year_1*bouwwaarde_perc)*
    # the remaining value
    weight_vector_perceelwaarde_FV = repmat(-1234, 1, size(immediate_loss_of_value_percent,2))
    for (current_nr_of_years_local in 1:size(immediate_loss_of_value_percent,2)) {
      
      # (-perceelwaarde_perc *cash_flow_year_1)
      weight_vector_perceelwaarde_FV[current_nr_of_years_local] = (-perceelwaarde_perc *cash_flow_year_1)*((1+groeivoet_waarde_perceel)^current_nr_of_years_local)
      # weight_vector_perceelwaarde_FV[current_nr_of_years_local] = (-perceelwaarde_perc *cash_flow_year_1)*((1+groeivoet_waarde_perceel)^current_nr_of_years_local)
      
      # weight_vector_perceelwaarde_FV
      
      # ,current_nr_of_years,groeivoet_waarde_perceel      # 
      # -bouwwaarde_perc*cash_flow_year_1
       # end_of_life_value_perc_local = [RV_loop, current_nr_of_years] = 
      
    }
    
  
    
    # depecriation_vec_bouwwaarde*bouwwaarde_perc
    # weight_vector_perceelwaarde_FV*perceelwaarde_perc
    weighted_average_residual_value_vec = weight_vector_perceelwaarde_FV + (bouwwaarde_perc*remaining_value_vec_bouwwaarde)
    
    weight_vector_perceelwaarde_FV
    (bouwwaarde_perc*remaining_value_vec_bouwwaarde)
    
    browser()
    
  }
  
  # weighted_average_depreciation_matrix[RV_loop_local,:] = weighted_average_depreciation_vector
  # weighted_average_depreciation_matrix <- cbind(x, y, z)
  #simulation_bouwwaarde = end_of_life_value_perc_temp[1]-jaarlijks_afschrijfpercentage_bouwwaarde*20
  
  # finVal = 1 * (0.0125 + 1)^20
  

  
  
  # return(...)
  
  
}
```

Version

RStudio 2021.09.2+382 "Ghost Orchid" Release (fc9e217980ee9320126e33cdf334d4f4e105dc4f, 2022-01-04) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

Comment: Is this function part of a package? If so, how exactly do you build it?

Comment: No, it is a custom written function. I add it by setting setwd() to the correct path in a cloud based location.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem in a Shiny app